# Why does this Fibonnacci recursion fails to return an answer for n > 2?

Tags: r, recursion

This recursion code doesn't give an output for n > 2. It works if I include the last if condition as else. Why does this happen?

```
fib <- function(n){

  if(n == 0){
    0
  }
  if(n ==1 ){
    1
  }
  if(n == 2){
   1
  } 
  if (n > 2) {
    print(n)
    fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A function by default returns the result of the last value evaluated inside the function. Here you have a bunch of separate `if` statements that will all be evaluated (your function doesn't return early at any point. Observe

```
f <- function(a) {
  -99
  if (a==1) {111}
  if (a==2) {22}
}
f(1)
# -- doesn't return anything --
f(2)
# [1] 22
f(3)
# -- doesn't return anything --
```

When 'a==1', That middle `if` statement would evaluate to `111` but that value is then discarded when you run the next `if` statement just like the `-99` value was before it. The last expression that was evaluated in this function is the `if (a==2) {22}` and that will either return `22` or it will return NULL. It won't return the previous values because it has no idea how those would be related without the `else` statement.

```
fib <- function(n){    
  if(n == 0){
    return(0)
  }
  if(n ==1 ){
    return(1)
  }
  if(n == 2){
   return(1)
  } 
  if (n > 2) {
    print(n)
    return(fib(n-1) + fib(n-2))
  }
}
```

Or you could turn those into if/else staments so only one "thing" will be returned

```
fib <- function(n){    
  if(n == 0){
    0
  } else if(n ==1 ){
    1
  } else if(n == 2){
   1
  } else if (n > 2) {
    print(n)
    fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
  }
}
```

Comment: The explicit return command seems to do nothing, and the else if do work. But I still don't understand the logic though. It keeps evaluating till the last and just breaks

Comment: What do you mean by "just breaks?" Function's don't just break on their own. You need an explicit return or just the result from the last expression is returned. In the code in your question, the last expression is the `if (n > 2) ` statement. That will only return something if that expression is true, otherwise it doesn't return anything

Comment: Let me give it a try. So, my question is what is the difference between having just an if statement and an else if at the end. I am a novice in R, so please bear with me. By break i just meant, it recurses till end and seemingly does nothing

Comment: And if/else is basically one statement.  It will return something from either the if block or the else block. But if you have two if statements. Only the second one will return anything. It will either return the if block if true, or it will return NULL if not true. It doesn't reach back to grab the value from the previous if statement.